# Gaussian Blur onHover Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I am wondering if there is some way to apply a gaussian blur onto a div using jQuery (or CSS that jQuery can modify).  I have looked into blur(), but at least with Safari, it doesn't seem that it accomplishes what I'm looking for.  If possible, I want to use fadeIn on the effect, so it blurs gradually.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be aware that `Blur` is when a DOM-element, such as textboxes (inputs etc.) loses focus, and should not be mixed with the kind of blur you are talking about (gaussian/motion blur).

There is no good cross-browser solution for this problem. You can, however, blur images by using a API such as the one Ben suggests. Or by [using this one](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/).

Maybe if you find out a way to draw your div contents to a HTML5 canvas you can then apply the Blur-filter by using [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/)?

Comment: To date I'm not aware of any good cross-browser solution for drawing DOM contents to a HTML5 canvas. There are a few techniques that work to a limited degree.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the blur.js plugin for jQuery: http://blurjs.com, it uses my Stack Blur algorithm which I believe is currently the fastest JavaScript based way to blur canvas elements: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

Answer (score 4):

```
filter: blur(10px);
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-o-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px);
filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='10');
```

content of blur.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

More : http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur

Comment: Please don't paste the same answer into multiple questions. if the questions are duplicates, please flag them as such. If they are not, then please tailor your answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

It has not been mentioned here that we can create an [excellent](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/creating-a-gaussian-blur-effect-with-css3/) realistic blur effect for text using CSS3 `text-shadow`. And, (yep, of course!) we can blur solid backgrounds and borders using `box-shadow`  (inset shadows and multiple shadows are allowed, you know).

So I hope in most cases you can achieve a realistic blur effect combining:

1) **image blur using canvas**

2) **text blur using** `text-shadow`

3) **solid background and borders blur using** `box-shadow`

4) have I forgotten anything else?....

---

PS: 
I believe it's not possible to write a magic class that blurs any html.

The restrictions that can't be overcome: blur the border of the image, blur embedded media

Comment: I looks like it's possible to blur a screenshot of the site http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/