# Blur image with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

Is there any way to blur images with JavaScript/jQuery so that when they are blured I can sharpen them by hovering them with the mouse?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966949/gaussian-blur-onhover-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) can do that for you. Here's the relevant doc: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/

To blur:

```
Pixastic.process(document.getElementById('demoimage'), 'blur');
```

To revert:

```
Pixastic.revert(document.getElementById('demoimage'));
```

The entire solution with jQuery:

```
var blur = function () {
    Pixastic.process(this, 'blur');
};

var unblur = function () {
    Pixastic.revert(this);
};

$('img').each(blur).hover(unblur, blur);
```

Comment: You sir are officially awesome! :D Thank you :)

Comment: you are wellcome ... didn't see the comment before :D ... i tried it and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for jQuery called blur.js http://blurjs.com which uses my very fast Stack Blur algorithm: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html