# Blur dialog window's background

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Is there a way to apply a blur effect to the whole background behind a modal window (created using jQuery-UI?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966949/gaussian-blur-onhover-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are some tricks to blur specific objects (text, SVG, for example), but nothing in CSS that can uniformly blur an entire document.

Comment: So, i guess i have to give up. Thank you anyway.